# PHP Add Seconds

Tags: php

For the life outta me, I checked through-out this forum and follow instruction, might have overlooked a thing or two.

Using:

```
$today = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A");
```

This will show me the accurate today's date/time, which I'm happy however, I'm trying to add seconds to the current date/time but keep giving me odd results.

```
$lSec = intval($str);
$lDay = intval($lSec / 86400);
$lHou = intval($lSec / 3600);
WHILE ($lHou >= 24) {
    $lHou = $lHou-24;
};
$lMin = intval(($lSec / 60) % 60);
$lSec = intval($lSec % 60);
return date(
    "m-d-Y H:i:s A",
    mktime(
        date("H")+$lHou,
        date("i")+$lMin,
        date("s")+$lSec,
        date("m")+0,
        date("d")+$lDay,
        date("Y")+0
    )
);
```

Is there anything I'm missing or is there anything better than this?  I even tried date_add and not giving me desirable result either.

Thanks!

P.S. Running on web host IIS7 with PHP 5 support.

Comment: If you can generate a UNIX timestamp value, why not just add relevant amount of seconds to that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding seconds to `time()`

```
$today = date( "m/d/Y h:i:s A", time() + 3600 ); // + 1 hour
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that:
Changed Code to: return date("m/d/Y h:i:s A",time()+intval($str));
Current Time: 08/13/2011 10:22:25 PM
Seconds to Add from $str ($str = 30800)
Result gave me: 08/14/2011 06:55:46 AM  <-why wrong output?

Comment: That is the correct output. 30800 seconds ~= 8.5 hours, which brings you from 10:22 PM to 6:55AM the next day.

Comment: Yes Kerry, you're correct.  For some reason my sleeping head keep fighting with me and tell me it's wrong cuz i have 2 results: 1 column tells me the time "d h m s" while this column displays the actual time (hence above) all the while, i forgot to incorperate the one column's setting into the 2nd column :) but yes the issue earlier remains that i couldn't add second to the time which is now resolved.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `intval($str)` seconds to the current time, and format the resulting date?

```
date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", time() + intval($str));
```

[`time`](http://php.net/time) gives the current time in seconds, and [`date`](http://php.net/date) accepts a time in seconds.

Comment: Ok, I tried that:
Changed Code to: return date("m/d/Y h:i:s A",time()+intval($str));
Current Time: 08/13/2011 10:22:25 PM
Seconds to Add from $str ($str = 30800)
Result gave me: 08/14/2011 06:55:46 AM  <-why wrong output?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateval= "04/07/2016 6:58:00";
$endDate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("+1 seconds",strtotime($dateval)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 30 seconds from right now:

```
$halfMinuteLater = strtotime("+30 seconds");

$formmatedTime = date('H:i:s', $halfMinuteLater);
```